# Can't make has_many realtionship with Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have these models:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :terminal_values
end

class TerminalValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

And this is `spec/factories.rb`:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company do
    sequence(:code){|n| n + 1000 }
  end

  factory :terminal_value do
    company
  end
end
```

To test a `has_many` relationship I wrote this test:

```
  it do
    company = create(:company)
    create(:terminal_value, company: company)
    expect(company.terminal_values.first).to_not eq(nil)
  end
```

But the test fails. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This may help https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations, https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/549

Comment: I could pass the test with `expect(company.reload.terminal_values.first)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Even though in your example you are providing company for the terminal  object, while declaring factory you have to provide complete definition, you can try this:

factory :company do
    sequence(:code){|n| n + 1000 }
  end

factory :terminal_value do
    company {build(:company)}
  end

Also post the error you are getting when running the test.

Comment: I tried with your example but the result was not changed as far as I noticed. I could solve the problem following advice of  @Sontya . Thanks anyway for your answer!